# ReservedOp, the usage of st ()

Tags: haskell

I want to make a Haskell parser for some mathematical expresions. For that, I would like to use reservedOp to define the operators. I tried to find some info and I found this example:

```
reservedOp :: String -> CharParser st ()
reservedOp = PT.reservedOp lexer
```

I searched on google, even on hoogle :) but couldn't find any explanation for that `st ()`. Can anyone explain me in a few words what's the deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CharParser` is just a type synonym. The main parser type used for parsing `ParsecT` has a lot of type variables and a lot of functionality that is often unused. The full type is

```
newtype ParsecT s u m a = ...
```

`s` is the parser state, `u` is the user state, `m` is the underlying monad, and `a` the return value.
If none of that makes sense, you should read about [monad transformers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers).

But that probably isn't important to understanding `CharParser`. You can follow the type synonyms

```
>:i CharParser
type CharParser st = GenParser Char st

>:i GenParser
type GenParser tok st = Parsec [tok] st

>:i GenParser
type GenParser tok st = Parsec [tok] st

>:i Parsec
type Parsec s u = ParsecT s u Identity
```

to discover that `CharParser st ()` is just `ParsecT [Char] st Identity ()`. That's a parser which operates on a stream of `Char` (aka a `String`), whose user state is *anything*, and which returns nothing. The only way the user state can be anything at all is if it is never used by anyone. So it means pretty much nothing, you could have written any of

```
reservedOp :: String -> CharParser () ()
reservedOp :: String -> CharParser Int ()
reservedOp :: String -> CharParser Bool ()
```

etc. If the user state is unused, then it is customary to write `CharParser () ()` to indicate that (some would say that is wrong and it should be `CharParser Void ()` where `data Void` is an uninhabited type, but that is just pedantry). In fact the author in your link *did* do that in most of their type signatures (ie, `factor :: CharParser () Double`)

Answer (score 1):

Since `st` is in lowercase, it's just a (type) variable name. Look up `CharParser` to see what it's all about.

Comment: I thought so, but I can't find anything to make sense for me. Here is the full code example: http://haskelladdict.wordpress.com/page/7/